# Using two R scripts in a PowerBI dashboard where script B depends on script A

Tags: r, powerbi

I am trying to translate some code that we previously used in a software similar to PowerBI into some form that's compatible with PowerBI. One thing that I need to do for that is to generate a model fit to some data and use that to display some data on the fit (in some further visual elements).

From a sequential point of view, this is trivial. Generate an object, then work on that object and print some data. But from what I understand about PowerBI, this kind of interdependency between R scripts / visual elements (generate an object, then hand that object to other procedures to generate further output) is not intended and since I need to use several visual elements, and all of them depend on the output of the first, I have no idea how to work this out.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use several visual elements, and all of them depend on the output of the first

Then the data needs to be created in Power Query and loaded into the data model.    You can run [R in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-r-in-query-editor) to generate the data, and visualize it with regular Power BI Visuals and the [R Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-r-visuals).

Comment: Well, don't I feel silly now. I was not aware that you could run R scripts in Power Query. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think my relief might have been a bit premature. What I need is to be able to access my ML fit in other R scripts. But from what I understand, power query is only meant to be used to transform the data tables that you have loaded in Power BI?